# Android foursquare:How can i know that whether check in has done or not?

Tags: android, foursquare

I am working on an Android application in which I want to integrate foursquare check-in. I have done my work till display of venues. Now when i select one place among the places in list.

Then i want to know how I can know whether the user has checked in that place successfully or not.

i am using this code.

```
try {
    // Construct data
    String data = URLEncoder.encode("ll", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(""+lat+" ,"+lon+" ", "UTF-8");

    data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("venueId", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(mNearbyList.get(position).id, "UTF-8");
    data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("oauth_token", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(mSession.getAccessToken(), "UTF-8");

    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
    wr.write(data);
    wr.flush();


    // Get the response
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.v(TAG,"Exception occur");
    }
    }
});
```

Please help me. What should I write now to check whether user has checked in or not. I really need your help. You can give your suggestions very freely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are performing the checking, so as described [here](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/checkins/add) - you will get back a checkin object.

The checkin object is described [here](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/responses/checkin) (following the link at the end of the checking/add api link just provided).
If you get that checkin object and not an error it means the checkin worked (there is a checkin id with that object)